# Comma expected error in useEffect data React

Tags: react-native, use-effect

I got "," (comma) expected error from data: {...sample.data, res.data} the error points to dot "." of res.data

```
useEffect(()=>{
     axios.get('http://localhost:1234/hello').then((res)=>{
          {console.log(res.data)}
          setSample({
            ...sample,
            data: {...sample.data, res.data}
          })
          {console.log(sample)}
     })
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to spread the `res.data` too.. Consider the below example

```js
  const [sample, setSample] = useState({data: {value: 'initial'}});

  useEffect(() => {
    const res = {
      data: {
       another_value: "from api"
      }
    };

    setSample({
      ...sample,
      data: { ...sample.data, ...res.data }
    });
    
  }, []);
```

The initial state of `sample` has property `value` with value = initial. In the `useEffect`, we are adding one more value to the sample object. This will result in an output,

```js
{value: "initial", another_value: "from api"}
```

also the `console.log(sample)` won't show the updated value if you log it just below the `setSample`. You might wanna add a `useEffect` with `sample` as dependency and it will listen to the changes in sample.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(sample);
  }, [sample]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Square braket

```js
useEffect(()=>{
     axios.get('http://localhost:1234/hello').then((res)=>{
          console.log(res.data);
          setSample({
            ...sample,
            data: {...sample["data"], ...res["data"]}
          });
          console.log(sample) // this not working because setSample is Promise function
     })
  }, [])
```

Comment: I'm still getting "," and  ":" expected error in res["data"]

Comment: @Vista Oh.. i'm missing spread I updated answer